# My datastore PropertyLoadSaver does not work in golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The documentation I used (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface)

Just using this struct without using the propertyLoadSaver everything works.

```
type Trick struct {
    Name string `json:"name" datastore:"-"`
    Difficulty int `json:"difficulty"`
}
```

When only using a load property it also works.

```
func (s *Trick) Load(c <-chan datastore.Property) error {
    return datastore.LoadStruct(s, c)
}
```

The save property results into a appengine panic at the return line?

```
func (s *Trick) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(c)
    return datastore.SaveStruct(s, c)
}
```

When I try this instead it will not result into a panic but does not save anything?

```
func (s *Trick) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(c)
    c <- datastore.Property{
        Name:  "Difficulty",
        Value: s.Difficulty,
    }
    return nil
}
```

(Using sdk v1.9.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `defer close(c)` will cause a panic

```
func (s *Trick) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(c)
    return datastore.SaveStruct(s, c)
}
```

The following is ok

```
func (s *Trick) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    return datastore.SaveStruct(s, c)
}
```

This is also ok

```
func (s *Trick) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(c)
    c <- datastore.Property{
        Name:  "Difficulty",
        Value: int64(s.Difficulty),
    }
    return nil
}
```

(please edit the documentation to make this more clear https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface)